# Filter multi-indexed dataframe based on lower dimensional values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to filter a multi-indexed DataFrame based on another DataFrame with a lower dimensional index, like in the following example:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df1 = io.StringIO('''\
ID1        ID2       ID3    Value   
1          1001      1        1
1          1001      2        2
1          1002      1        9
2          1001      1        3
2          1002      2        4
''')

df2 = io.StringIO('''\
ID1        ID2      Value   
1          1001    2
2          1002    3
''')

expected_result = io.StringIO('''\
ID1        ID2       ID3    Value   
1          1001      1        1
1          1001      2        2
2          1002      2        4
''')

df1 = pd.read_table(df1, sep='\s+').set_index(['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'])
df2 = pd.read_table(df2, sep='\s+').set_index(['ID1', 'ID2'])
expected_result = (pd.read_table(expected_result, sep='\s+')
                   .set_index(['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']))

assert all(df1.loc[d2.index] == expected_result) # won't work
```

If both dataframes have the same dimension one can simply:

```
df1.loc[df2.index]
```

which is equivalent to a list of same dimension indices, e.g.

```
df1.loc[(1, 1001, 1), (1, 1001, 2)]
```

It is also possible to select single elements based on a lower dimensional index like so:

```
d1.loc[(1, 1001)]
```

But how can I filter based on a list (or other index) with lower dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list comparison can be done with `isin`: first drop the additional dimensions from the index of the higher dimensional dataframe and then compare the remains with the index of the lower dimensional one. In this case:

```
 mask = df1.index.droplevel(2).isin(df2.index)
 assert all(df1[mask] == expected_result) # passes
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems a bit tricky to get your desired result. As with pandas 0.19.2, the multi index label locater `loc` seems to be buggy when supplying an iterable of exactly defined rows:

```
# this should give the correct result
desired_rows = ((1, 1001, 1), (1, 1001, 2), (2, 1002, 2))

# messes up with varying levels 
print(df1.loc[desired_rows, :])

                    Value
ID1     ID2     ID3     
1       1001    2   2

# when reducing the index to the first two same levels, it works
print(df1.loc[desired_rows[:2], :])

                    Value
ID1     ID2     ID3     
1       1001    1   1
2                   2
```

Therefore, we can't rely on `loc` for your given example. In contrast, the multiindex index locator `iloc` still works as expected. However, it requires you to get the corresponding index locations which is shown below:

```
df2_indices = set(df2.index.get_values())
df2_levels = len(df2.index.levels)

indices = [idx for idx, index in enumerate(df1.index) 
           if index[:df2_levels] in df2_indices]

print(df1.iloc[indices, :])

                    Value
ID1     ID2     ID3     
1       1001    1   1
2                   2
2       1002    2   4
```

#### Update 15.07.2017

An easier solution is to simply convert the `desired_rows` tuples to a list because the `loc` works more consistently with lists as a row locator:

```
df1.loc[list(desired_rows), :]

                        Value
ID1     ID2     ID3     
1       1001    1           1
                2           2
2       1002    2           4
```

Comment: I believe this doesn't do what I want but my example wasn't the best one. The issue here is that all combinations of level 0 and level 1 values will be accepted, which is not what I want. I only want exactly the combinations that are in the second dataframe. I will update the example.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. Good idea moving to the index locator! Unfortunately this is a rather complicated solution as well; but maybe that's the only way to go.

Comment: @TimTröndle Yes, unfortunately it is rather complicated. It would have been more simple in case the `loc` would work appropriately.

Comment: @TimTröndle Updated the answer due to some new knowledge of a nice pandas sprint. The new solutions is way easier :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by passing the individual index level values and then [`slice(None)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) for the non-existent 3rd index level:

```
In [107]:
df1.loc[df2.index.get_level_values(0), df2.index.get_level_values(1),slice(None)]

Out[107]:
              Value
ID1 ID2  ID3       
1   1001 1        1
         2        2
2   1001 1        3
         2        4
```

Then we can see that all values match:

```
In [111]:
all(df1.loc[df2.index.get_level_values(0), df2.index.get_level_values(1),slice(None)] == expected_result)

Out[111]:
True
```

The problem is that because the indices are not the same dimensions you need to specify what to pass for the non-existent 3rd level, here passing `slice(None)` will select all rows for that level so the masking will work

Comment: I believe this doesn't do what I want but my example wasn't the best one. The issue here is that all combinations of level 0 and level 1 values will be accepted, which is not what I want. I only want exactly the combinations that are in the second dataframe. I will update the example.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to temporarily reduce the dimension of the higher dimensional index to then do a same-dimension filtering:

```
 result = (df1.reset_index().set_index(['ID1', 'ID2']).loc[df2.index]
           .reset_index().set_index(['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']))
 assert all(result == expected_result) # will pass
```

It's quite involved though.